# Hey I need to grep services from nmap output

Tags: xml, grep, nmap

So i have a project where i need to get the services so i can check them on serchsploit
(yes i know about the -oX and the --nmap options but it dosent show the exect stuff that i need)

```
 # Nmap 7.93 scan initiated Fri May 19 12:53:56 2023 as: nmap -sV -oG test.txt 192.168.0.15
Host: 192.168.0.15 ()   Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.15 ()   Ports: 21/open/tcp//ftp//vsftpd 2.3.4/, 22/open/tcp//ssh//OpenSSH 4.7p1 Debian 8ubuntu1 (protocol 2.0)/, 23/open/tcp//telnet//Linux telnetd/, 25/open/tcp//smtp//Postfix smtpd/, 53/open/tcp//domain//ISC BIND 9.4.2/, 80/open/tcp//http//Apache httpd 2.2.8 ((Ubuntu) DAV|2)/, 111/open/tcp//rpcbind//2 (RPC #100000)/, 139/open/tcp//netbios-ssn//Samba smbd 3.X - 4.X (workgroup: WORKGROUP)/, 445/open/tcp//netbios-ssn//Samba smbd 3.X - 4.X (workgroup: WORKGROUP)/, 512/open/tcp//exec//netkit-rsh rexecd/, 513/open/tcp//login?///, 514/open/tcp//tcpwrapped///, 1099/open/tcp//java-rmi//GNU Classpath grmiregistry/, 1524/open/tcp//bindshell//Metasploitable root shell/, 2049/open/tcp//nfs//2-4 (RPC #100003)/, 2121/open/tcp//ftp//ProFTPD 1.3.1/, 3306/open/tcp//mysql//MySQL 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5/, 5432/open/tcp//postgresql//PostgreSQL DB 8.3.0 - 8.3.7/, 5900/open/tcp//vnc//VNC (protocol 3.3)/, 6000/open/tcp//X11//(access denied)/, 6667/open/tcp//irc//UnrealIRCd (Admin email admin@Metasploitable.LAN)/, 8009/open/tcp//ajp13//Apache Jserv (Protocol v1.3)/, 8180/open/tcp//http//Apache Tomcat|Coyote JSP engine 1.1/  Ignored State: closed (977)
# Nmap done at Fri May 19 12:54:08 2023 -- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.88 seconds
```

I tried to get the colums in -oN output and also get them -oX by greping product and version and -oG
greping the whats in betwin // and /, but yet no luck

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). also, read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try to grep like this:

```
nmap -sV [target_ip] | grep -i 'service:'
```